# Is there a CSS only solution to :hover on touchscreens?

Tags: html, css

I know there are many solutions with JS, but non of them work perfectly for me. Is there a solution with pure css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new Level 4 Media Queries, this issue seems like it’s solved for good.

```
@media(hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {}
```

- [Media Queries 4 Hover](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#descdef-media-hover)
- [Media Queries 4 Pointer](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#descdef-media-pointer)